# Two active directory forests, find corresponding exchange active directory object / mailbox

Tags: active-directory, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

the company I work for has 2 Active Directory forests. One forest is called us where I log on in the morning with my profile (us\maflorin) and another forest is called (mail.us) which is dedicated to Exchange.

I have created an asp.net application that runs on SharePoint and gets the SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName which is the us domain login name. (us\maflorin for example for me). I would like to get from the us credentials the corresponding object on the Exchange forest in order to write changes to the global address list (GAL) for user that opened the page after a line manager approval process.

I wrote the following working code to get the Exchange object, but it uses two ldap queries to find the object:

```
private Dictionary<string,AdRecod> FindExchangeAdProperties(string samAccountName,string description)
 {
        Dictionary<string,AdRecod> properties = null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(samAccountName))
        {
            properties = GetUserProperties(@"(&(objectCategory=person)(mailNickname=" +
                                               samAccountName + "))");
            if (properties != null) return properties;
         }

        if ((description == "") || (description == "0"))
            throw new Exception("No matching Description, couldn't find correct Exchange AD object");

        properties = GetUserProperties(@"(&(objectCategory=person)(description=" +
                                       description + "))");
        return properties;
 }
```

Is it possible to get the exchange object with a single ldap query directly from the us samAccountName?

The mailNickname attribute on the exchange forest does not always match the sAMAccountName on the us forest. If it does not match, I use the second ldap query to see if a record is return by querying on the description field. The description field is many times the same for both forests but sometimes an administrator changed it.

Is it possible to find the corresponding Exchange Active Directory object for the us domain credentials more easily? How does Outlook find from the us credentials the corresponding mailbox / Ad object ? I was looking at the AD schema with adsiedit but could not find a clear field that is used to link the two forest objects together.

Furthermore I was looking into the Autodiscover service of the exchange web services managed api (mailbox dn attribute) but you need to pass into the GetUserSettings method an SMTP address and this field is not populated on the us domain.

Many thanks,

Mathias

Comment: What version of exchange are you using?

Comment: Exchange 2007, thanks for looking into this question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to find an answer to this question with a better approach than the one above which depends on the company's naming convention.

On the exchange forest I run a LDAP query with the DirectorySearcher class to obtain the attribute msExchMasterAccountSid.

The following code then provides the correct sam on the forest we use to logon:

```
var sid = directoryEntry.Properties["msExchMasterAccountSid"].Value as byte[];
// no mailbox
if (sid == null) continue;

var sidString = new SecurityIdentifier(sid, 0).ToString();
var samAccountName = "";
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "US"))
{
       var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.Sid, sidString);
       if (principal == null) continue;
       samAccountName = principal.SamAccountName;
}
```